# Unable to upload multiple files using alamofire from source URL- swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am attempting to upload an image file(.jpg) and a pdf file(.pdf) at the ssme time using Alamofire.  I keep getting the following error which indicates that the files that I am trying to upload does not exist, which in fact they do.

```
 multipartEncodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.MultipartEncodingFailureReason.bodyPartFileNotReachableWithError(atURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7FF74F06-CD6E-47D6-850E-45E768C00D97/Documents/tempImage_wb.jpg, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “tempImage_wb.jpg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7FF74F06-CD6E-47D6-850E-45E768C00D97/Documents/tempImage_wb.jpg, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7FF74F06-CD6E-47D6-850E-45E768C00D97/Documents/tempImage_wb.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c4841020 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}))
```

My code for uploading the files:

```
 // GET URL FOR IMAGE AND PDF FILES
    guard
        let imageURLString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "URL_IMAGE"),
        let pdfURLString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "URL_PDF") else{return}


    guard
        let imgURL = URL.init(string: imageURLString),
        let pdfURL = URL.init(string: pdfURLString) else{return}

    var arrayURLToUpload: [URL] = []
    arrayURLToUpload.append(imgURL)
    arrayURLToUpload.append(pdfURL)



 let sendParamters = ["user_id": "1", "hashTagArray": jsonArrayHashTags]
    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            for(key, value) in sendParamters{
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8)!), withName: key)
            }

            for fileURL in arrayURLToUpload{
                print("fileURL: \(fileURL)")
                multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: "file[]")
            }
    },
        to: UPLOAD_URL,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }

                /**TRACK PROGRESS OF UPLOAD**/
                upload.uploadProgress { progress in
                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)


                }
                /***/


            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

console:

```
 fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7FF74F06-CD6E-47D6-850E-45E768C00D97/Documents/tempImage_wb.jpg
 fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7FF74F06-CD6E-47D6-850E-45E768C00D97/Documents/tempImagePDF.pdf
```

I know the files exist becuase when I retrieve one of the files (.pdf) and display it I am able to view the stored pdf file:

```
    guard let urlString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "URL_PDF") else{return}

    guard let pdfURL = URL.init(string: urlString) else{
        print("no pdf URL")
        return

    }
    print("pdfURL: \(pdfURL)")

    guard let pdf = PDFDocument.init(url: pdfURL) else{
        print("NO PDF DOCUMENT FOUND")
        return

    }

    pdfPreview.document = pdf // CAN VIEW PDF FILE!!!
    pdfPreview.autoScales = true

    print("pdf document displayed!")
```

console:

```
 pdfURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/90ECD1AE-B9A5-46C9-AD30-C5D8D850A361/Documents/tempImagePDF.pdf

 pdf document displayed!
```

How I generate my URLs:

```
 // Create a URL to save PDF
func createPdfURL() -> URL {

    let fileName = "tempImagePDF.pdf"

    let documentsDirectories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = documentsDirectories.first!
    let pdfPageURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")

    return pdfPageURL
}
```

Then I save the PDF document as follows:

```
 // SAVE PDF TO LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
func savePdfToLocaFile(pdf: PDFDocument) -> Void {

    // CREATE URL FOR PDF DOCUMENT
    let pdfURL = createPdfURL()
    print("PDF SAVED TO URL: \(pdfURL)")

    self.pdfDocumentURL = pdfURL

    pdf.write(to: pdfURL)


}
```

I have also tried the following to retrieve the files by reconstructing the URL from the file name before using it to upload the files:

```
 // CONSTRUCT URL FROM FILE NAME
    let imgFileName = "tempImage_wb.jpg"
    let pdfFileName = "tempImagePDF.pdf"

    var dir: URL!
    do {
        dir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    } catch{
        print("error re-creating url")
    }

    let imgURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(imgFileName)
    let pdfURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(pdfFileName)
```

new console reading after implementing @vadian's suggestion:

```
PDF SAVED TO URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35C9D3EE-2D0C-4028-BCF3-2FE4581A0686/Documents/tempImagePDF.pdf
fileURL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35C9D3EE-2D0C-4028-BCF3-2FE4581A0686/Documents/tempImagePDF.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the different application container identifier `7FF74F06-CD6E-47D6-850E-45E768C00D97` and `90ECD1AE-B9A5-46C9-AD30-C5D8D850A36`.

Container locations change periodically therefore never save full paths pointing to the application container to `UserDefaults`.
Save only the file names and get the URL to the current document directory always with

```
let documentsFolderURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

Then append the file name with `.appendingPathComponent`

Note: The `try!` is safe because the *document* directory is always created by the framework.

Comment: why does document url not change and photo url changes?